# After delete a variable and then reload the module,how can I make the namespace not retain this variable?

Tags: python, reload

"reload" function cannot delete variable which have loaded into memory if you delete it in your module before reload. In another words, even if you delete the variable before reload, it will still exist.

According to the ([DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)):

> When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained.

Here's a simple example:

```
import importlib
import time
def main():
    import ex1
    i = 0
    while True:
        importlib.reload(ex1)
        ex1.x = ex1.x + 1
        i = i + 1
        print("loop:%d" %i)
        print("x:%d" %ex1.x)
        print(dir(ex1))
        time.sleep(5)
```

ex1 module's content before reload:

```
x = 1
y = 1
```

Then delete `x` and reload `ex1` and we will find that `x` is still in the `dir(ex1)`

So, my question is how can I get a `dict` in which `x` is not in the `dir` after delete and reload?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Use of `reload()` in normal code is usually not recommended.

Comment: Is this [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: If you have the value of `x, y` in `ex1`, of course each time `x, y` will be present again when `ex1` is reloaded.  If you however `del ex1.x` and not reload, then `ex1.x` will be gone from your namespace.

Comment: @Idlehands Thank you for your answer and yes,it can make it . But I don't want to change the code in `ex1`.

Comment: @StephenRauch `ex1` module only have `x` and `y`. This is just small example to explain my question. So in actual I have more variables,functions and classes

Comment: @Tangwei, click the link in comment above.  This is the same problem as your question.  You need to read everything.

Comment: @Blurp I would like to make a framework just like hot-fix to fix some bugs dynamically in module-level .

Comment: @StephenRauch Oh,thank you for your suggestion.  But actually that's really what I want to fix. I can't get the ideal result after I delete the variable and then `reload` the module .  As the goals, I would like to make a dynamical update framework just like hot-fix so I would like to update the global namespace, deleting or adding something.

Comment: So we are back to [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Did you read the [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) link?  What is it you are trying to accomplish?  I answered your question.  You can not do what you asked.

Comment: @Tangwei, I'm a bit confused.  You said you don't want to change the code in `ex1`, but I thought your question is you want to reload the module because `x` is deleted and you no longer want it in your namespace?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yeah,I have read it . Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Idlehands Yes,your idea is right but not the ideal one. I would like to make  something like hot-fix which need two different kinks of modules ---- modules before update and modules after changed.So I need to deal with the namespace of the main module. If I add `del` explicitly but not the usual way of delete , it'll become hard to manage and maintain. But if I add variables or change the value of variables, I needn't care too much  because python will deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not read far enough, after the sentence you quoted comes:

> Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, the old definition remains.

So, the sentence you quoted only applies to variables that were defined in the old version of the module, but are not defined in the new version of the module.

So to your Question:

> So, my question is how can I get a `dict` in which `x` is not in the `dir` after delete and reload?

The answer is you can't.  You can however do:

```
del ex1.x
```

After the reload.

Comment: It's `del ex1.x`, they used `import ex1`, not `from ex1 import x, y`.

Comment: Why I can't make it ? What about changing `reload` 's implementation mechanism?Or `import`

Comment: Well of course you can implement your own Python too.  Bu that seems like it was out of scope of your question.